# Zxing Iphone qr code reader

Tags: iphone, qr-code

how do I add particular actions like sending SMS or URL open according to the qr code image, i have been using zxing library and scantest app,any example code?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list

Download code from above given link and ran it on your device it will working.

Comment: Thnx for your response  but I have already downloaded and Scantest example is running fine in which The Application is scanning the code and gives the result in text View, What I want now to use the actions on that result . The actions like open URL and SMS according to the result.The actions headers and main files are given to but how to call them?

Comment: @ahsan, i also work on same project, i also downloaded project from given link and it work fine for me and out put which gave same that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Barcodes app in iphone/Barcodes. It ties into the result parser infrastructure in iphone/ZXingWidget.

I haven't actually used this code, but I know others have been trying to keep it up to date.